# rsync include exclude is excruciatingly slow

Tags: find, rsync

When I use `rsync` to copy files matching a pattern à la https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2503/288916 this works but it is excruciatingly slow. `find` locates the matching files much faster. (Like more than 10 times faster.) Is this normal? Can anything be done about this?

It seems like the better strategy is to just use find and copy only the matching results one by one (with `scp` or `rsync`).

---

Example command (see also the linked question for the explanation of the purpose of the command):

```
rsync -am --include='*.pdf' --include='*/' --exclude='*' ~/LaTeX/ ~/Output/
```

Comment: Roughly how many directories and files to scan? Are `~/LaTeX` or `~/Output` on a non-native filesystem such as FAT or NTFS, or on any kind of network filesystem?

Comment: As a comparison point, using `--include='*.*'` as my local equivalent to your first include, a tree of 52 directories and 168 files takes 0.05s to scan (`rsync --dry-run --verbose ...`). One with 1858 directories and 308 files still takes only 0.08s. I'm not convinced it's directly an `rsync` issue, hence the questions about filesystems, etc.

Comment: I was applying it to a directory tree containing 376569 files. `find` takes roughly 20 seconds while `rsync` takes roughly 2 minutes. Not familiar with file systems but `stat -f -c %T .` returns `gpfs`  (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21870/288916). It is also interesting that `find` seems to be doing some buffering so that the second same search or even just roughly similar is instantaneous.

Comment: Let me get some performance points for a filesystem with ~ 300K files...

Comment: I am no longer sure I am doing a fair comparison. I have to redo my test. Perhaps rsync was just slower because I ran it first in both my tests. See https://serverfault.com/a/626492/601435. Edit: Well rsync is still slow even after a similar rsync command or after the find command. But the difference could perhaps still be in `find` using data stored in ram better.

Answer (score 1):

When you compare `find` and `rsync` bear in mind that you're not really comparing like for like:

- `find` is only scanning the source filetree,
- `rsync` is not only scanning the source filetree but also doing a metadata comparison to the corresponding destination file (size, datetime, permissions, ownership) to see whether it needs to copy the source across to the target.

I'm not familiar with GPFS but it seems to be a [clustering filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPFS), which means that your file accesses are also also potentially network bound. However, after the first run-through of the filesystem your Linux-based system will have done its best to cache the file tree so that subsequent accesses are memory based. I get a 30x speed increase on a tree of 140000 files just from this one optimisation.

For comparison you could consider the following code closer to the `rsync` implementation shown in your question. I have found it's about 200x slower than the corresponding raw `find` even before the `mkdir` and `cp` are considered (prefix them with a `:` no-op to prevent their action).

```
cd ~/LaTeX &&
    find . -type f -name '*.pdf' |
        while IFS= read -r src
        do
            dst=~/Output/"$src"
            if [ ! -f "$dst" ] || [ "$(stat -c '%s-%Y' -- "$src")" != "$(stat -c '%s-%Y' -- "$dst")" ]
            then
                mkdir -p -- "${dst%/*}"
                cp -p -- "$src" "$dst"
            fi
        done
```

It's definitely not as clever as `rsync` but I believe it's a fair starting point.

Finally, if you want to drive the file selection into `rsync` with `find` you can do that too:

```
cd ~/LaTeX &&
    find . -type f -name '*.pdf' -print0 |
        rsync -av --files-from - --from0 ./ ~/Output/
```

If you don't have `find … -print0` replace it with `-print` and remove `--from0` too. You may hit issues with edge-case file names (those containing newlines and other less common characters) but for most file names it will continue to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for all the effort! As for the difference, in the specific test case I had there were only 1 or 2 matches. I would expect that the fact that `rsync` does an extra comparison on a match therefore would change very little performance wise. (If implemented well it should not be looking at any meta data for files it already knows it is not going to act on.)
I found using `find` and then `rsync` on the specific files that I found to be much faster than rsync alone (and this still does all the relevant comparisons that rsync should be doing since it is used at the end).

Comment: And indeed `find` definitely seems to be using the cached information much better.

Comment: It is possible to feed files from `find` into `rsync` - answer updated for that too, @Kvothe